# Using parts of sliced string in python

Tags: python

My task is doing a base converter. I thought of switching it to base 10 and then switch it to the wanted base. So I want to get a string and them put it in a list, and slice it and after that to use the sliced parts:

```
s=input()
NumList=[s]
NumList[::]
```

Is there any way of doing it? Do you have any better idea?

Comment: I've re-read the question a couple of times, and can't make heads nor tails of it.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I can understand that you want to convert numbers from one base to another base. But I cannot understand anything past that point. What does converting numbers between bases have to do with slicing strings?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try to clear it:

Comment: my input should be at this form: 1111 2 5 (means the number 1111 in base 2 needs to be switched to base 5)

Answer (score 1):

You split up your input string like this:

`(number, from_base, to_base) = s.split()`

Comment: thank you!
i tried now to do power: from_base^i(some variable)

Comment: while(i,pow(from_base,i),i+1) :
     sum+=i

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string received from input by space and thereafter process it according to your needs.

```
s = input()
ls = s.split() // ls is a list.
```

Comment: just `s.split()` space (`' '`) is default